# Easy mate in three

Tags: problems

This time an easy puzzle I made up today. White mates in three.

```
[FEN "7k/4Kp2/P4Np1/6R1/8/R6P/8/8 w - - 1 0"]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
[fen "7k/4Kp2/P4Np1/6R1/8/R6P/8/8 w - - 1 0"]

1. Rh5+ gxh5 {if Kg7, Rh7#}
2. Rg3  h4
3. Rg8#
```

Comment: Oh, I had another solution in mind. Can you find it?

Answer (score 7):

Herb's solution works perfectly, but since you indicated in a comment that you were expecting for another one, maybe that's it.

```
[fen "7k/4Kp2/P4Np1/6R1/8/R6P/8/8 w - - 1 0"]

1. Rag3 Kg7
2. Rh5 g5
3. Rgxg5#
```

---

**Edit**:

Here is a simple suggestion to fix the cook and make this solution the only one:

```
[fen "7k/4Kp2/P4Np1/6R1/7P/R7/8/8 w - - 1 0"]

1. Rag3 (1.Rh5? gxh5 2.Rg3? {stalemate}) (1.h5 Kg7) Kg7
2. Rh5 g5
3. Rgxg5#
```

Comment: Yes, this is the one i meant. Unfortunately it's a bad puzzle because it has two solutions. I overlooked that.

Comment: It should not be too hard to avoid the cook. Anyway, having two solutions is acceptable for an exercise, but not for a problem.